# How to add small card logos to Stripe Checkout Payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

[This is what it looks like the payment settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1z4A.png)

other stripe methods have the option by default but this doesn't

[I want to add these kind of icons to the end of the payment method at checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM7g6.png)